# how to determine whether a particular row is present in the viewport of table body or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table having 100 rows with scroll bar.At any point of time only 5 rows can be seen in the viewport of table body.

I tried using .is(:visible) but it working even if the row is out of the viewport of table body.

Comment: share code what you have tried?

Comment: I recommend using a JS library like Waypoint JS to do whatever you like http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: You need to calculate whether its visible based on the row's Y coordinate and the window's scrolling Y and height.

Comment: Linked duplicate question is discussing a plugin.  That also has a linked duplicate that doesn't use a plugin (but does use jQuery)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling